# Extension news: localize an image or a content element

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 7.6,18
news 6.0.0
two languages

I create a new news arcticle, and add an image and add a content Element.
Then i translate the new article to english (list view, flag)

Then i want tzo localize my image and my content element, but the button "Alle Datensätze lokalisieren" doesn't do anything.

[image]Any idea?

Comment: it seems do be a core bug:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some information here:

IRRE: "Localize all records" and "Synchronize with default language" not working anymore
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80855